# JMH project in Eclipse: Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to run [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) benchmarks from inside Eclipse. It's a Maven (m2e) project, the `pom.xml` includes the correct dependencies (`jmh-core` and `jmh-generator-annprocess`, v1.9.3), the project compiles in Eclipse and the benchmarks can be run on the commandline via `mvn clean install` and `java -jar target/benchmarks.jar`. However, when I try to run one of the [samples](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/) from Eclipse (*Run As > Java Application*), I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ERROR: Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList
    at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.AbstractResourceReader.getReaders(AbstractResourceReader.java:96)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkList.find(BenchmarkList.java:104)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.internalRun(Runner.java:251)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:203)
    at example.JMHSample_01_HelloWorld.main(JMHSample_01_HelloWorld.java:100)
```

Annotation processing is enabled in the project properties. The file `/META-INF/BenchmarkList` is created by a maven build, but not by an Eclipse build. Why?

**Update:**

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397542/no-matching-benchmarks-when-running-jmh-from-main-in-eclipse) about JMH and Eclipse but it's about a very old JMH version and a different error message. I'd like to understand the reason for this problem, i.e. is the annotation not being processed or is the generated code not found etc.

Comment: ...and, JMH 0.9.3 is *VERY* old; 1.9.3 seems to be the latest now.

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo, I'm actually using version 1.9.3. Updated, thanks!